# Cloud Datastore PHP returning 0 results

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

So I tried to first see if my PHP can talk to Datastore and retrieve data.
I created two entities under the kind "keypad_research".

This is how my PHP looks like:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\Entity;
$projectId = "__my projectID__";
$datasetId = $projectId;
$datastore = new DatastoreClient(['projectId' => $projectId]);

function getlist($datastore){
    $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind('keypad_research')
        ->start($cursor);

    $results = $datastore->runQuery($query);
    $entries = [];
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($results as $entity) {
        $count++;
    }

    echo $count; // this shows me '0' results even when I have 2 entities.
}
getlist($datastore);
?>
```

As you can see in the echo statement in the end, it is resulting in 0 rows of data.

Do I need to do any addition configuration or edit my PHP to be able to read from datastore?

My very basic attempt at reading data from datastore using PHP is failing.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying a non-default namespace, you need to identify the namespace when you [initialize your client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.86.0/datastore/datastoreclient):

```
$datastore = new DatastoreClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'namespaceId' => 'my-namespace'
    ]);
```

Comment: WOW, such an important information is nowhere to be found in the documentation. Thanks a ton, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get the number of entities in a kind using your code, only editing the second line and adding the variable `$cursor=null`:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\Entity;

$projectId = "__my projectID__";
$datasetId = $projectId;
$datastore = new DatastoreClient(['projectId' => $projectId]);

function getlist($datastore){
$cursor=null;
        $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind('keypad_research')
        ->start($cursor);

    $results = $datastore->runQuery($query);
    $entries = [];
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($results as $entity) {
        $count++;
    }

    echo $count; // this shows me '0' results even when I have 2 entities.
}
getlist($datastore);
?>
```

Comment: Oh thats great. But even after adding the cursor code I don't get any results. Do you know if there could be Authentication issue? Do I need anything else other than this code for it to work?

Comment: Could the namespace be a problem? My Kind is not default namespace, it has specific namespace defined.